tensorflow back compatibility: KerasTensor and tf-keras tensor
I have some code written with tensorflow 2.3 in which tensors are constructed using tf.keras.
As moving to tensorflow > 2.16, tf.keras is retired an tf calls keras >= 3.0.
The type of the tensors in my code changes from tf.Tensor to Keras.Tensor. As a consequence, my code is largely affected, most of which raises the following error
ValueError: A KerasTensor cannot be used as input to a TensorFlow function. A KerasTensor is a symbolic placeholder for a shape and dtype, used when constructing Keras Functional models or Keras Functions. You can only use it as input to a Keras layer or a Keras operation (from the namespaces keras.layers and keras.operations). You are likely doing something like:
x = Input(...)
...
tf_fn(x)  # Invalid.

What you should do instead is wrap tf_fn in a layer:
class MyLayer(Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        return tf_fn(x)
x = MyLayer()(x)

So is there a simple solution to solve this or do I need to apply this wrapper everywhere?
Update 2024-09-11
Let me try to make the question more solid. Consider the following example. It is taken from function get_decoder_mask in google tft module
In TF 2.3, using tf.keras, we can define the following tenor for masking as follows.
Define
t = keras.layers.Input(shape=(250, 5), name="input")
which is tf.Tensor.
len_s = tf.shape(t)[-2]
bs = tf.shape(t)[:-2]
mask = tf.cumsum(tf.eye(len_s, batch_shape=bs), -2)

In TF 2.17, only native keras is available.
t = keras.layers.Input(shape=(250, 5), name="input")  

which is KerasTensor. Then the following code does not work.
len_s = tf.shape(t)[-2]
bs = tf.shape(t)[:-2]
mask = tf.cumsum(tf.eye(len_s, batch_shape=bs), -2)

With tf.shape(t) being replaced with t.shape, the code breaks further down at tf.eye(...).

You can implement keras layers instead of using tf functions directly.

@Dr.Snoopy I have tf_fun(Keras.Tensor) all over the space. So the best solution for me would be convert Keras.Tensor to tf.Tensor when it's being created. In this way the code does not require changes in subsequent operations.

That's not possible, you would have to provide more information to give a better answer.

@Dr.Snoopy Example updated.

Those three operations could be implemented in a single Keras layer, as I said, you should start to think in terms for layers, not individual operations.
